# Quitar signos de puntuación

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentado quitar los signos de puntuación de un DataFrame, pero no parece tener efecto con el siguiente código

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from pandas import DataFrame
import string

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SBMDEBPBDD08V\VAI;'
                      'Database=DMIN_AUDITORIA;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor() ##ejecutar codigó SQL
resoverall = cursor.execute('SELECT TOP (100) CAMPO_NOTA FROM DMIN_AUDITORIA.reclamos.DATOS2014v2')

df = DataFrame(resoverall.fetchall()) #paso a dataframe
datos=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\sburitic\\example.xlsx') #leo en excel
datos.columns = ['numeracion', 'Campo Nota']#renombro las columnas 
datos = datos.drop(['numeracion'], axis=1) #elimino columna
datos = datos.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())#paso los datos a minuscula
for puntuacion in string.punctuation:
    datos = datos.replace(puntuacion, ' ')
```

Me gustaría saber que otras opciones hay o que estoy haciendo mal

---

Logre solucionarlo transformando el tipo de dato de datos astring, y ya aplicando la función replace, pero espero obtener mas sugerencias ya que no creo que sea la mejor solucion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a)

```
datos = datos.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[^\w\s]',''))
```

b)

```
import string
datos = datos.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), ''))
```

## EDIT:

La primera opción se trata de: primero modificar los datos a tipo string y luego aplicar replace con una expresión regular. Recordemos que replace puede usar regex, por lo que en este primer caso le estamos pidiendo que reemplace todo lo que **no (^)** sean **word character (\w)** o sea alfanuméricos o **espacios (\s)**, por carácter vacio ('').

La segunda opción la he incluido por que el OP estaba usando directamente una lista de signos de puntuación. Funciona parecido a la anterior, solo que aquí substituimos la expresión regular por los signos incluidos en `string.punctuation`.

La diferencia entre ellas es que la primera opción eliminara **cualquier** cosa que no sean letras, números o espacios en blanco; mientras que la segunda **solo** eliminara los símbolos que estén en la lista especificada.

Comment: ¿Podrías dar una explicación de las dos opciones? De cómo funciona cada una y que ventajas/desventajas tienen

Comment: Hecho, espero que ahora quede mas claro.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte las molestias :)